# Can Doxygen sort members of member groups alphabetically by name?

Tags: grouping, doxygen

I am documenting a very large namespace (Fortran module holding a lot of global variables). At first I just configured Doxygen to alphabetize the output. Then I thought it would be useful to group the items into member groups.  However I don't seem to be able to achieve both at once. If I use member groups, the elements are not sorted alphabetically. Is there a configuration to make it happen? I'm not talking about alphabetizing the groups -- the configuration for that seems well documented. Thanks.